# ios In-App Purchase when buying multiple of same item

Tags: ios, user-interface, in-app-purchase

The iOS in-App purchase when purchasing multiple items, such as credits.

**Confirm Your In-App Purchase**
Do you want to buy one 5 Credits for $3.99

where it would be better to have a dialog that stated:
Do you want to buy 5 Credits for $3.99

Anybody else run into this?   Is there a way to have the better dialog text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup, I've run into it. :-) I don't think there's a way to change that wording, unfortunately. (Although, there should be!)

The only thing you control is the name of the thing being purchased. I ran into this myself. Your only alternative (at least that I am aware of) is to name your IAP products so that they "read" nicely in that dialog. So your "5 Credits" might be better named "Credit 5 Pack". When you read "Do you want to buy one Credit 5-Pack for $3.99?" at least it sounds like English. :-)